# Select query error: no such table

Tags: android, sqlite

Im trying to retrieve data from my database table called details. However when im running the query the exception "no such table" is thrown.

Below is the query.

```
Cursor c = mDb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM details", null);
```

No error is being thrown when values are inserted into the same table.

What have I missed?

Comment: Please add code where you think you are creating the table.

Comment: Table was created manually and Plus insertion into the same table is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Look into your `Database`, your table `"details"` doesn´t exist or the name is incorrect.

Check if `SQLiteDatabase` (mDb) is loading the same Database where you have inserted the data.